# List in dictionary as a template definition

Tags: arrays, swift, templates, dictionary

I'm using arrays which are stored in a dictionray for fast access. Because I need this logic for different data types, I like to define it as a template, but I don't have any idea how to pass types. In my own description it should look like this:

```
struct KeyList {
    let key : MyType1
    var list = [MyType2]()

    init(key : MyType1, value : MyType2) {
        self.key = key
        self.list.append(value)
    }
}


    var dicList = [String: KeyList]()

    value = ...of MyType2
    key = ... of MyType1

    if dicList[key] == nil {
            // new entry
            dicList[key] = KeyList(key: key, value: value)
        }
        else {
            // add it to existing list
            dicList[key]!.list.append(value)
        }
    }
```

But I want to use Swift 3. Any idea, if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a couple of things:

1. generics
2. encapsulation

### Snippet

Here's an example

```
struct Container<Key, Value> where Key: Hashable {

    private var dict: [Key:[Value]] = [:]


    func list(by key: Key) -> [Value]? {
        return dict[key]
    }

    mutating func add(value: Value, to key: Key) {
        dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? []) + [value]
    }

}
```

### Usage

Now you can create a `Container` specifying the `Key` and the `Value` types

```
var container = Container<String, Int>()
container.add(value: 1, to: "a")
container.add(value: 2, to: "a")
container.list(by: "a") // [1, 2]
```

### Update

You asked in the comments how to implement a **remove functionality**. In this case the Value needs to be `Equatable`. Here's the code

```
struct Container<Key, Value> where Key: Hashable, Value: Equatable {

    private var dict: [Key:[Value]] = [:]


    func list(by key: Key) -> [Value]? {
        return dict[key]
    }

    mutating func add(value: Value, to key: Key) {
        dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? []) + [value]
    }

    mutating func remove(value: Value, from key: Key) {
        guard var list = dict[key] else { return }
        guard let index = list.index(of: value) else { return }
        list.remove(at: index)
        dict[key] = list
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that realy cool. Thank you very much. That's exactly what I searched for.

Comment: One question: How can I access value in generics? I try to remove an item, but "let newList = list.filter() { $0 != value }" is invalid: (type 'Any.Type? -> Bool' to expected '(_) -> Bool'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This way is much easier :-) If you know it. But there is an error, that "Cannot invoke  'index' with an argument list of type '(of: Value)'". Value is a class name in my app!

Comment: @Peter71: I tried with a  class and it works fine. My code is for Swift 3.

Comment: I also use Swift 3, but my Class is maybe to complicated?

Comment: @Peter71: Are you sure your class is `Equatable`?

Comment: :-) No, it's not! :-) but it is Comparable. Isn't that better? I now added Equatable, but was rejected as "redundant"

Comment: @Peter71: Ok, if it's `Comparable` than is also `Equatable`. Can you show me your full code?

Comment: I added one file. It's already a lot of stuff. :-) The key definition as container is "var dicByFilenameExtUC = Container<String, DSPhotoFile>()" So this collects items of type DSPhotoFile. Itself it is DSPhotoFiles.

Comment: Yes too much code :) Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to build it from scratch. See you later (in some days ;-) )

Comment: I got it. It was so easy. You updated your code inbetween, but I didn't realized it. "struct Container<Key, Value> where Key: Hashable, Value: Equatable" was the key to success. (adding ", Value: Equatable") Thank you very very much.